# Testing SQL Server connectivity from remote using custom port is not working

Tags: sql-server, powershell, connection-string, powershell-5.0

I am trying to test the `SQL Server` connectivity from a remote machine in the network using a `power shell` script mentioned below.

```
$dbhost = 'che-wv001\'
$dbinst = 'MSSQLSERVER'
$dbport = 'MSSQLSERVER,6755'
$dbname = 'master'
$driverName = 'SQL Server'

$username = 'user'
$password = 'user'

$cs = "Driver=$driverName;Server=$dbhost$dbport;Database=$dbname;User ID=$username;" +
      "Password=$password;"   

echo "ConnectionStr : $cs"

$cn = New-Object -COM 'ADODB.Connection'
$cn.ConnectionString = $cs
try {
  $cn.Open()
  if ($cn.State -eq 1) {
    'Connection Success'
    $cn.Close()
  } else {
    'not connected'
  }
} catch {
  echo $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message
  #'not connected due to exception exception'
}
```

Instead of a named instance I have used a custom port 6755 to create the SQL Server. I have no problems connecting to the server via SQL Server Management Studio using `che-wv001\MSSQLSERVER,6755` giving the user credentials. But for some reason, the PowerShell script throws the following error when I run from my machine:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Specified SQL server not found.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that the extra variable `$dbinst` is not being used? It doesn't have the port and is confusingly similar to `$dbport` - which includes more than just the port. Oh, and why a COM object?

Comment: My previous code was working fine for testing connection string for DB servers created with instance name. I have changed a bit to make it work to test server created with database port as well and facing this issue.

Comment: Your connection string is not correct. An instance name is effectively a substitute for the port. To specify a non-standard port (without using the browser service - why?), you use <hostname,port>. A big long discussion [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134499/what-are-valid-connection-strings-for-ssms-login-box)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use the connection string with the below syntax and connect to the database.

```
$cnString = "Data Source=Server\instance,port;Initial Catalog=master;Trusted_Connection=true;"
$cn = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection($cnstring)
$cnSql = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection($cn)
$s = New-Object Microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server($cnSql)
$s | Select Name, Version
```

Comment: The connection logic was fine. My current code is good enough. It was the firewall restrictions that created the problem. Disabling the firewall completely rectified the problem. Sorry for the trouble...

Comment: No Trouble dude. Happy coding